# What is causing data to be erased by adding a domain in ArcGIS 10.2.2 and ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online, domains

I have spatial data in ArcGIS 10.2.2 that I'm sharing as a Service and then viewing in ArcGIS Online. The data consist of the first and last name of employees, separated by a single space, i.e. 'John Smith'. Last names have been omitted in the example screen
 capture below representing the successful display of the data.

[image]

I would like to add a domain to a pre-populated field that constrains input into this field. The problem is that when I add this domain in ArcMap 10.2.2 and then share the result as a Service and then view it as a Map, the data itself no longer displays in ArcGIS Online.

Below is an example of the domain constraints. I have made certian that each name already present in the database is represented in the domain definition, to ensure that the issue is not that pre-existing data are not allowed within the new domain.

[image]

And finally, here is the result in ArcGIS Online when the domain above is applied to the Field of employee names.

[image]

Why might this be happening and what can I do to solve it?

**Edit:**
To make this even more unnerving, I followed the advice of Adding a Field, setting the Domain, then populating via Field Calculator, and it still didn't work!

[image]

Comment: Agol is picky, bracket in alias might cause trouble. Try single field dataset, simple alias, might help to trace culprit